# Format a Date String with Time zone and return Date object

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I need to format a string date with given time zone and return the date object back. I am currently in IST time zone.

So IST is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of UTC.

```
public void getDate(){
  String dateStr = "11/25/2016T13:30:00.000";
  String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
  Date date = formatedStringToDate(dateStr, dateFormat);
  System.out.println(date);
}

public static Date formatedStringToDate(final String date, final String dateFormat) throws ParseException {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date parsedDate = null;
        if (date != null) {
            try {
                parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return parsedDate;
}
```

I get the below out put.

```
Fri Nov 25 19:00:00 **IST** 2016
```

The time seems to be change from 5.30 hours but then if its a IST to UCT time converstion, it should be 5.30 hours before 13:30:00 which is 08:00:00?

Also how could I change the highlighted IST part of out put string to show the currect time zone in this case UTC?

Comment: No. India Standard Time (IST) is 5:30 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). So, since your date represents 13:30 UTC, and IST is 5:30 ahead, 13:30 UTC = 19:00 IST. A Date doesn't have any time zone. It's just a universal moment in time, stored as a number of milliseconds since another precise moment. To format it in UTC, then use a SimpleDateFormat, whose timezone is set to UTC, just like the one you used to parse the string (but you'll get the original string, then, of course).

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. So this is my understanding now. dateStr  is just a string value with out any time zone. So I want to get the Date object by convert the time to given time zone. So in this example I set sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); Then I should not be have any time conversion know because my dateStr  is in UTC and I set UTC also in my SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 2):

When you call `toString` on a `Date` (by printing it) you get the *default* format (because a `Date` is an object that stores a number of milliseconds, or nanoseconds in Java 9+, since an epoch). To see the result in UTC you need something like,

```
final DateFormat sdf = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,
        DateFormat.FULL);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = formatedStringToDate(dateStr, dateFormat);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // <-- format the Date
```

Comment: For my curiosity, are they really changing the precision of java.util.Date in Java 9, although it's already basically deprecated in favor of the java.time API?

Comment: @JBNizet I had heard they were, but now I cannot find a primary source. I believe it's to do with the `Date` implementation, the public api doesn't change (regardless of how Java is internally defining the epoch).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for point it out. Actually I print it just for my view purpose and I understand what is more important is the millisecond value which get assign in the Date constructor. So in that case, suppose I have a String date with time as in my example dateStr = "11/25/2016T13:30:00.000" in UTC (No time zone information is provided in the string so by default its UTC right) and I want to convert it to time for given time zone. eg: PST,UTC,IST etc. What could I do additionally in my example code post in the question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Also with my current code posted, why I am getting a time converstion because my dateStr also in UTC and SimpleDateFormat I set timezone as UTC?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2017-11-25T13:30:00.000" )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )
```

> 2017-11-25T13:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that replaced the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Parse your input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) given the lack of any indicator of zone or offset-from-UTC.

Using standard ISO 8601 format for such strings is preferred. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2017-11-25T13:30:00.000" ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2017-11-25T13:30

If you are certain this date-time was intended to represent a moment by the wall-clock time of India, then assign a time zone to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-11-25T13:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

You can adjust into another zone for comparison.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal") );
```

> zdtMontreal.toString(): 2017-11-25T03:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

To parse/generate strings in other formats such as the one in your Question, use the `DateTimeFormatter` or `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` classes. Search Stack Overflow for more info, as these have been covered extensively.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" , Locale.US ) ;
```

Use that formatter for parsing.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "11/25/2016T13:30:00.000" , f ) ;
```

And for generating.

```
String output = ldt.format( f ) ;  // Generate string.
```

Consider using ISO 8601 formats instead.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).